# What is the role of probability in machine learning software?

Tags: machine-learning, integration

There are several components and techniques used in learning programs.  Machine learning components include ANN, Bayesian networks, SVM, PCA and other probability based methods. What role do Bayesian networks based techniques play in machine learning?

Also it would be helpful to know how does integrating one or more of these components into applications lead to real solutions, and how does software deal with limited knowledge and still produce sufficiently reliable results.

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't look like a programming question

Comment: Agree - I'd recommend removing from SO and posting over at [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 2):

**Probability and Learning**

Probability plays a role in all learning.  If we apply Shannon's information theory, the movement of probability toward one of the extremes 0.0 or 1.0 is information.  Shannon defined a bit as the quotient of the log_2 of the before and after probabilities of a hypothesis.  Given the probability of the hypothesis and its logical inversion, if the probability does not increase for either, no bits of information have been learned.

**Bayesian Approaches**

Bayesian Networks are directed graphs that represents causality hypotheses.  They are generally represented as nodes with conditions connected by arrows that represent the hypothetical causes and corresponding effects. Algorithms have been developed based on Bayes' Theorem that attempt to statistically analyze causality from data that had been or is being collected.

MINOR SIDE NOTE:  There are often usage constraints for the analytic tools.  Most Bayesian algorithms require that the directed graph be acyclic, meaning that no series of arrows exist between two or more nodes anywhere in the graph that create a purely clockwise or purely counterclockwise closed loop. This is to avoid endless loops, however there may be now or in the future algorithms that work with cycles and handle them seamlessly from mathematical theory and software usability perspectives.

**Application to Learning**

The application to learning is that the probabilities calculated can be used to predict potential control mechanisms.  The litmus test for learning is the ability to reliably alter the future through controls.  An important application is the sorting of mail from handwriting.  Both neural nets and Naive Bayesian classifiers can be useful in general pattern recognition integrated into routing or manipulation robotics.

Keep in mind here that the term network has a very wide meaning.  Neural Nets are not at all the same approach as Bayesian Networks, although they may be applied to similar problem-solution topologies.

**Relation to Other Approaches and Mechanisms**

How a system designer uses support vector machines, principle component analysis, neural nets, and Bayesian networks in multivariate time series analysis (MTSA) varies from author to author.  How they tie together also depends on the problem domain and statistical qualities of the data set, including size, skew, sparseness, and the number of dimensions.

The list given includes only four of a much larger set of machine learning tools.  For instance Fuzzy Logic combines weights and production system (rule based) approaches.

The year is also a factor.  An answer given now might be stale next year.  If I were to write software given the same predictive or control goals as I was given ten years ago, I might combine various techniques entirely differently. I would certainly have a plethora of additional libraries and comparative studies to read and analyse before drawing my system topology.

The field is quite active.